# Python3.5 is not in the /usr/local/Cellar/opencv3/3.1.0_3/lib path as expected

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, opencv3.0, pyenv

Why there's no python3.5 in the following path? I have installed OpenCV3 for Python3 using homebrew. You can find the complete homebrew gist for this [here](https://gist.github.com/monajalal/fae307db63c777fefe3ac496ec328465).

According to this tutorial I should have it after following the steps (so bad I don't know the language the tutorial is written in):
http://qiita.com/HirofumiYashima/items/eb697b1e359586b538e6

```
ls /usr/local/Cellar/opencv3/3.1.0_3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cv2.so
```

I expect to have the following:

```
ls /usr/local/Cellar/opencv3/3.1.0_3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/cv2.cpython-35m-darwin.so
```

Any insight would be super useful!

```
bash-4.3$ python
Python 3.5.2 (default, Jul 28 2016, 21:28:07)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 7.0.2 (clang-700.1.81)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
```

and

```
bash-4.3$ brew info opencv3 | grep python3
  Built from source on 2016-07-30 at 22:49:10 with: --with-python3 --with-contrib
--with-python3
    Build with python3 support
bash-4.3$ brew install opencv3 --with-python3
Warning: homebrew/science/opencv3-3.1.0_3 already installed

bash-4.3$ brew install opencv3
Warning: homebrew/science/opencv3-3.1.0_3 already installed

bash-4.3$ pyenv versions
* system (set by /Users/mona/.pyenv/cache/.python-version)
  3.5.0
  3.5.2
```

Just a little extra information:

```
bash-4.3$ uname -a
Darwin Monas-MacBook-Pro.local 15.6.0 Darwin Kernel Version 15.6.0: Thu Jun 23 18:25:34 PDT 2016; root:xnu-3248.60.10~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64
```

Thanks a lot!

---

My bash_profile:

```
 ~/.bash_profile
  1 export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/go/bin
  2
  3 [[ -s "$HOME/.profile" ]] && source "$HOME/.profile" # Load the default .profile
  4
  5 [[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*
  6
  7 # Setting PATH for Python 3.4
  8 # The orginal version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
  9 PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin:${PATH}"
 10 export PATH
 11
 12 # added by Anaconda2 2.4.1 installer
 13 export PATH="/Users/mona/anaconda/bin:$PATH"
 14
 15 compresspdf() {
 16       gs -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dNOPAUSE -dQUIET -dBATCH -dPDFSETTINGS=/${3:-"screen"} -dCompatibilityLevel=1.4 -sOutputFile=$2 $1
 17     }
 18
 19
 20 export PATH="/usr/local/sbin:$PATH"
 21 export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
 22 export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/local/bin/python3
 23 source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
 24 export PYENV_ROOT="$HOME/.pyenv"
 25 export PATH="$PYENV_ROOT/bin:$PATH"
 26 export PATH="~/.pyenv/bin:$PATH"
 27 eval "$(pyenv init -)"
 28 eval "$(pyenv virtualenv-init -)"
```

UPDATE: I installed opencv3 and installed it again with python3. However as you see only Python2.7 shows in the installed lib:

```
bash-4.3$ brew install opencv3 --with-python3
==> Installing opencv3 from homebrew/science
==> Downloading https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/archive/3.1.0.tar.gz
==> Downloading from https://codeload.github.com/opencv/opencv/tar.gz/3.1.0
######################################################################## 100.0%
==> Downloading https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/commit/a2bda999211e8be9fbc5d40038fdfc9399de31fc.diff
==> Downloading from https://github.com/opencv/opencv/commit/a2bda999211e8be9fbc5d40038fdfc9399de31fc.diff
######################################################################## 100.0%
==> Downloading https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/commit/c7bdbef5042dadfe032dfb5d80f9b90bec830371.diff
==> Downloading from https://github.com/opencv/opencv/commit/c7bdbef5042dadfe032dfb5d80f9b90bec830371.diff
######################################################################## 100.0%
==> Downloading https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/commit/cdb9c60dcb65e04e7c0bd6bef9b86841191c785a.diff
==> Downloading from https://github.com/opencv/opencv/commit/cdb9c60dcb65e04e7c0bd6bef9b86841191c785a.diff
######################################################################## 100.0%
==> Patching
==> Applying a2bda999211e8be9fbc5d40038fdfc9399de31fc.diff
patching file modules/videoio/src/cap_qtkit.mm
==> Applying c7bdbef5042dadfe032dfb5d80f9b90bec830371.diff
patching file modules/core/include/opencv2/core/opencl/runtime/autogenerated/opencl_gl.hpp
Hunk #1 succeeded at 45 (offset 4 lines).
Hunk #2 succeeded at 58 (offset 4 lines).
patching file modules/core/include/opencv2/core/opencl/runtime/autogenerated/opencl_gl_wrappers.hpp
patching file modules/core/src/opencl/runtime/autogenerated/opencl_gl_impl.hpp
patching file modules/core/src/opencl/runtime/generator/common.py
patching file modules/core/src/opencl/runtime/generator/template/opencl_gl.hpp.in
Hunk #1 succeeded at 12 (offset 4 lines).
patching file modules/core/src/opencl/runtime/generator/template/opencl_gl_impl.hpp.in
patching file modules/core/src/opencl/runtime/generator/template/opencl_gl_wrappers.hpp.in
patching file modules/core/src/opencl/runtime/opencl_core.cpp
Hunk #1 succeeded at 283 (offset -3 lines).
Hunk #2 succeeded at 305 (offset -3 lines).
patching file modules/core/src/opengl.cpp
==> Applying cdb9c60dcb65e04e7c0bd6bef9b86841191c785a.diff
patching file samples/gpu/CMakeLists.txt
==> Downloading https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Itseez/opencv_3rdparty/81a676001ca8075ada498583e4166079e5744668/ippicv/ippicv_macosx_20151201.tgz
######################################################################## 100.0%
==> cmake .. -DCMAKE_C_FLAGS_RELEASE=-DNDEBUG -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE=-DNDEBUG -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local/Cellar/opencv3/3.1.0_3 -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -D
==> make
==> make install
==> Caveats
This formula is keg-only, which means it was not symlinked into /usr/local.

opencv3 and opencv install many of the same files.

Generally there are no consequences of this for you. If you build your
own software and it requires this formula, you'll need to add to your
build variables:

    LDFLAGS:  -L/usr/local/opt/opencv3/lib
    CPPFLAGS: -I/usr/local/opt/opencv3/include


If you need Python to find bindings for this keg-only formula, run:
  echo /usr/local/opt/opencv3/lib/python2.7/site-packages >> /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/opencv3.pth
==> Summary
  /usr/local/Cellar/opencv3/3.1.0_3: 281 files, 119M, built in 6 minutes 12 seconds
```

and I have:

```
bash-4.3$ ls /usr/local/Cellar/opencv3/3.1.0_3/lib/
libopencv_calib3d.3.1.0.dylib       libopencv_highgui.3.1.dylib     libopencv_objdetect.dylib       libopencv_video.3.1.0.dylib
libopencv_calib3d.3.1.dylib     libopencv_highgui.dylib         libopencv_photo.3.1.0.dylib     libopencv_video.3.1.dylib
libopencv_calib3d.dylib         libopencv_imgcodecs.3.1.0.dylib     libopencv_photo.3.1.dylib       libopencv_video.dylib
libopencv_core.3.1.0.dylib      libopencv_imgcodecs.3.1.dylib       libopencv_photo.dylib           libopencv_videoio.3.1.0.dylib
libopencv_core.3.1.dylib        libopencv_imgcodecs.dylib       libopencv_shape.3.1.0.dylib     libopencv_videoio.3.1.dylib
libopencv_core.dylib            libopencv_imgproc.3.1.0.dylib       libopencv_shape.3.1.dylib       libopencv_videoio.dylib
libopencv_features2d.3.1.0.dylib    libopencv_imgproc.3.1.dylib     libopencv_shape.dylib           libopencv_videostab.3.1.0.dylib
libopencv_features2d.3.1.dylib      libopencv_imgproc.dylib         libopencv_stitching.3.1.0.dylib     libopencv_videostab.3.1.dylib
libopencv_features2d.dylib      libopencv_ml.3.1.0.dylib        libopencv_stitching.3.1.dylib       libopencv_videostab.dylib
libopencv_flann.3.1.0.dylib     libopencv_ml.3.1.dylib          libopencv_stitching.dylib       pkgconfig
libopencv_flann.3.1.dylib       libopencv_ml.dylib          libopencv_superres.3.1.0.dylib      python2.7
libopencv_flann.dylib           libopencv_objdetect.3.1.0.dylib     libopencv_superres.3.1.dylib
libopencv_highgui.3.1.0.dylib       libopencv_objdetect.3.1.dylib       libopencv_superres.dylib
```

Here's what brew info tells about opencv3:

```
bash-4.3$ brew info opencv3
homebrew/science/opencv3: stable 3.1.0 (bottled), HEAD [keg-only]
Open source computer vision library, version 3
http://opencv.org/
/usr/local/Cellar/opencv3/3.1.0_3 (281 files, 119M)
  Built from source on 2016-08-02 at 18:54:26 with: --with-python3
From: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-science/blob/master/opencv3.rb
==> Dependencies
Build: cmake ✔, pkg-config ✔
Required: jpeg ✔, libpng ✔, libtiff ✔
Recommended: eigen ✔, openexr ✔, homebrew/python/numpy ✔
Optional: ffmpeg ✔, gphoto2 ✘, gstreamer ✘, jasper ✘, libdc1394 ✘, openni ✘, openni2 ✘, qt ✔, qt5 ✘, tbb ✔, vtk ✔
==> Options
--32-bit
    Build 32-bit only
--c++11
    Build using C++11 mode
--with-contrib
    Build "extra" contributed modules
--with-cuda
    Build with CUDA v7.0+ support
--with-examples
    Install C and python examples (sources)
--with-ffmpeg
    Build with ffmpeg support
--with-gphoto2
    Build with gphoto2 support
--with-gstreamer
    Build with gstreamer support
--with-jasper
    Build with jasper support
--with-java
    Build with Java support
--with-libdc1394
    Build with libdc1394 support
--with-opengl
    Build with OpenGL support (must use --with-qt5)
--with-openni
    Build with openni support
--with-openni2
    Build with openni2 support
--with-python3
    Build with python3 support
--with-qt
    Build the Qt4 backend to HighGUI
--with-qt5
    Build the Qt5 backend to HighGUI
--with-quicktime
    Use QuickTime for Video I/O instead of QTKit
--with-static
    Build static libraries
--with-tbb
    Enable parallel code in OpenCV using Intel TBB
--with-vtk
    Build with vtk support
--without-eigen
    Build without eigen support
--without-numpy
    Use a numpy you've installed yourself instead of a Homebrew-packaged numpy
--without-opencl
    Disable GPU code in OpenCV using OpenCL
--without-openexr
    Build without openexr support
--without-python
    Build without Python support
--without-test
    Build without accuracy & performance tests
--HEAD
    Install HEAD version
==> Caveats
This formula is keg-only, which means it was not symlinked into /usr/local.

opencv3 and opencv install many of the same files.

Generally there are no consequences of this for you. If you build your
own software and it requires this formula, you'll need to add to your
build variables:

    LDFLAGS:  -L/usr/local/opt/opencv3/lib
    CPPFLAGS: -I/usr/local/opt/opencv3/include
```

Comment: Can you try to reach that directory by using `cd` command to see if there is some error with the path, The easiest way to verify is to `cd /usr` then press `TAB` to see the various options for navigation and do this until you get the whole path verfied.

Comment: It doesn't exist at all

Comment: Are you using Mac OS X environment ? And which part of the path is invalid?

Comment: Yes osx El capitan. Please read the question carefully.

Comment: The the path must be partially valid, can you specify where the path becomes invalid ?

Comment: If you read the post carefully I have mentioned how much of the path exists

Comment: There seems so much of information already in the answer itself, I guess it may have the answer as well ... best of luck

Comment: hello @MonaJalal did you have any luck on a solution? Trying myself, have it installed for 2.7 but not 3.5

Comment: @redrubia no i am working with opencv2